# Task<IList<>> as a result of Func<>

Tags: c#, generics, task-parallel-library

I've tried to made wrap method for calling my async methods with some additional calculation:

```
private async Task<IEnumerable<Dictionary<string, object>>> Execute(Func<Task<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>> func)
{
  var ret = await func();
  // Skipped
  return ret;
}
```

it works perfectly for some cases:

```
var data = await Execute(() => chain.Start(parameters), args);
```

where chain.Start is

```
async Task<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>> Start(Dictionary<string, object> parameters)
```

but in some cases my func is not awaitable, so I've tried to return Task.FromResult in it.

```
var ret = Execute(() => Task.FormResult(new List<Dictionary<string, object>>());
```

and compilator said, that

> Error 24  Cannot convert lambda expression to delegate type
>   'System.Func>>>'
>   because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly
>   convertible to the delegate return type

Is this possible to use awaitable in this case? Or I should rewrite my code in sync manner?

Comment: [Offtopic] Dmytro, are you ukrainian?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The issue is that `Task<T>` is not covariant (and cannot be, since it is not an interface).

So when you write `Task.FromResult(new List<Dictionary<string, object>>())`, the return type of `FromResult` is `Task<List<Dictionary<string, object>>>`, which cannot be converted to `Task<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>`.

The solution is to specify the `FromResult` generic arguments explicitly:

```
var ret = Execute(() => Task.FormResult<IList<Dictionary<string, object>>>(
    new List<Dictionary<string, object>>());
```